# Need to pass the user input (date) into DB2 query in Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

The DB2 query below should be run with the date that the user entered.  How can I pass the user input date into the DB2 query which one highlighted in Bold.

```
#/usr/bin/ksh
db2 connect to sunrise user edwprod using prodedw1

echo "enter the date (format should be 20140829)"

read $DATE   # Read date here

result=`db2 "Select ORBDDT, count(*) as cnt_lines,
                    sum(ODAPRC * (cast(((coalesce(odsqty,1)/(case when odconv=0 then 1 else odconv end))) AS decimal (20,2)))) as sum_Sales,
                    sum(ODSQTY * ODAVCS) as sum_COGS
               from SFBASLIB.SFORDD
               JOIN SFBASLIB.SFORDR ON (ODORD# = ORORD# and ODLINK = ORLINK and ODSHP# = ORSHP#)
               JOIN SFBASLIB.SFORDH ON (OHORD# = ORORD# and OHLINK = ORLINK and OHORD# = ODORD# and OHLINK = ODLINK)
              where ORBDDT>='$DATE'
                and ODSQTY <> 0
                and ODSTAT not in ('SCR','CAN','BCN','KIL')
                and ORPSTA not in ('SCR','CAN','BCN')
                and ODITYP not in ('M','C')
                and OHTYPE not in ('RE','QU','TRAN')
              group by ORBDDT with UR"`

echo $result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the second invocation of `db2` was surrounded by back quotes (as now shown in the reformatted question), then the problem is in the `read` line.  It should be:

```
read DATE
```

You don't prefix the name with `$` in a `read` statement.  That was taking the value assigned to `$DATE` and trying to use that as the variable name, which doesn't work.

You should probably use `$(db2 "SELECT …")` notation in preference to the back quotes.  I assume you're going to do something more than just echo the result; otherwise, you shouldn't capture the output.  And even if you do just echo it, you should use:

```
echo "$result"
```

to preserve the internal spacing of the result.

I assume that you are able to create the connection with the first `db2` command and then run the query against the same connection with the second `db2` command.  And you'd better not have disclosed a production password.